# Undefined Method for wp-includes/post.php after being hacked

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

There's a lot of "undefined method" questions here but this is quite specific.

My WP site was hacked and while I've cleared out most of the issues, the links between pages and content isn't working and now I have access back to the dashboard - all the plugins have disappeared and when trying to view the existing pages, i get...

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method wpdb::get_col_charset() in /web1/user55663/website/wp-includes/post.php on line 3255**

and when I check, it is showing as...

```
    $charset = $wpdb->get_col_charset( $wpdb->posts, $emoji_field );
    if ( 'utf8' === $charset ) {
            $data[ $emoji_field ] = wp_encode_emoji( $data[ $emoji_field ] );
```

Now I'm not a developer/coder, but I'm proud to have at least recovered entry back to the site and deleted the hackers crap.

So any ideas as to where all the links have gone?

I'm using Divi theme at www.fentonward.com

Cheers for the help in advance

Comment: Be careful--WordPress hacks often leave malicious code in many different places. It's a good idea to at least replace the core WordPress code with a freshly downloaded version. Some security plugins will scan core files for you to ensure their integrity.

Comment: You may need someone to fix it. @JohnEllmore is right hackers leaves malicious code such as backdoors. If you are not an expert you can't do it your self so I suggest you hire one. You can have me if you want.

Comment: Cheers for those answers. And Mark - how much do you charge for doing something like this? Not a big site, just a business card site, no e-commerce, info gathering etc - very straight forward.